# convert image to Indexed black and white (1-bit) palette linux

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, gimp, indexed

I'm trying to convert (several) PNG files to an indexed black and white (1-bit) palette image in linux via a bash script (or C code). If I use Gimp and take menu options  Image,  Mode,  Indexed
I get the "Indexed Colour conversion" dialog and can select  "Use black and white (1-bit) palette"  and "Remove unused and duplicate colors from colormap" options.
If I then export the file I get a desired (black and white) indexed file.
I want to do this via bash or part of code (preferably c).

I've tried using a imagemagick convert with threshold of 50% this looks approx like what I want bit the output is greyscale not indexed.

Comment: Does this do what you want?  `convert lena.png -threshold 50% PNG8:x.png`

Comment: @fmw42 it does convert to indexed, but it has a bit depth of 8 which is not the 1-bit palette GIMP produces. Do you happen to know how to create a 1-bit indexed png? I tried `PNG1:x.png`, `-depth 1 -colors 2` and `-format PNG1`, neither of which worked

Comment: try `convert logo: -threshold 50% -define png:color-type=3 -define png:bit-depth=1 logo_1.png` otherwise, I do not know.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks, that worked! Thought I had already tried that but apparently not